# Ansible Synchronize not able to create directory as root

Tags: ansible

I'm working on building an Ansible playbook and I'm using Vagrant as a test platform before I apply the playbook to a remote server.

I'm having issues getting Synchronize to work.  I have some files that I need to move up to the server as part of the deployment.

Here's my playbook.  I put the `shell: whoami` in there to make sure commands were running as root.

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: who am I
      shell: whoami
    - name: Sync up www folder
      synchronize: src=www dest=/var
```

When I run this I get this:

```
failed: [default] => {"cmd": "rsync --delay-updates -FF --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -i /Users/dan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=2222' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' www vagrant@127.0.0.1:/var", "failed": true, "rc": 23}
msg: rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/var/www" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1236) [sender=3.1.1]


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

If I'm supplying `sudo: yes` shouldn't all commands be run as root, including Synchronize?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Ansible Synchronize module page](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html#notes) has some big hairy warnings:

> The remote user for the dest path will always be the remote_user, not
>   the sudo_user.

There's a suggestion to wrap `rsync` with `sudo` like this:

```
# Synchronize using an alternate rsync command
synchronize: src=some/relative/path dest=/some/absolute/path rsync_path="sudo rsync"
```

There's also a suggestion to use verbosity to debug what's really going on. In this case, it means adding `-vvv` or even `-vvvv` to your ansible-playbook commandline execution.

Finally, this is a great time to use proper permissions, especially for non-system files like a www dir. This will solve your problem in the process.

```
# don't use recurse here unless you are confident how it works with directories.
- file: dest=/var/www state=directory owner=www-data group=www-data mode=0755
- synchronize: src=www dest=/var
```

Comment: Love the suggestion about proper permissions.  So I tried it, but I get `msg: unsupported parameter for module: user`.

Comment: The `rsync_path` wrap worked for me, following up after with another task to ensure correct permissions.